# mySQL cannot create FK because incorrect timestamp values

Tags: mysql

Hi i am trying to add a new column which is a FK to another table, I added the new column but when I try to make it a FK im getting this error

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'created_at' at row 4383
```

that's what im trying to run:

```
ALTER TABLE smallstage_grouponi_groupon.tb_opportunity ADD chain_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE smallstage_grouponi_groupon.tb_opportunity ADD FOREIGN KEY (chain_id) REFERENCES tb_chains(id);
```

what it has to do with the `created_at` column? I am not even trying to alter it.
Please advise a solution

Answer (score 3):

You populated the tb_opportunity table with a SQL mode where "NO_ZERO_DATE" was disabled. At this time inserting datetimes like "0000-00-00 00:00:00" was allowed.

You are now trying to add a foreign key to this table, in a session where the SQL modes "strict" and "NO_ZERO_DATE" are enabled. The mysql engine has to reindex your table to add the foreign key, but throws an error because it encounters a line with a "0000-00-00 00:00:00" datetime, which isn't allowed anymore in this mode.

To bypass this, you'll have to either disable the NO_ZERO_DATE SQL mode, or to first fix the rows in your table where created_at equals "0000-00-00 00:00:00" before adding your foreign key.
Another option can also be to keep the NO_ZERO_DATE mode and disable the strict mode, which will produce a warning instead of an error.